# BigQuery - Filter voided from nested table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested-table

I have nested table like this:

```
BASKET-LEVEL                  PRODUCT_LEVEL             PAYMENT_LEVEL
id, gross_value,is_voided     gross_value, is_voided    amount, is_voided
                              gross_value, is_voided    amount, is_voided
```

I need to make sure that I have filtered out `is_voided = true` at each level of granularity.

What is the best approach to this problem?>

```
SELECT BL.* FROM BASKET-LEVEL AS BL
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(PRODUCT_LEVEL) AS PROD
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(PAYMENT_LEVEL) AS PAY
WHERE BL.isVoided is false
AND PROD.isVoided is false
AND PAY.isVoided is false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `EXISTS` like this, with a subselect that uses `UNNEST` and address an attribute

```
SELECT
* 
from `table`
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (
       SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST (product_level)  
       WHERE is_voided is true
      )
  AND NOT EXISTS
      (
       SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST (payment_level)  
       WHERE is_voided is true
      )
```